# NodeJS Child Process can't send net.socket fd:3

Tags: node.js, multithreading, sockets

When writing a nodejs multi-threading package there is the problem when the main thread can send content though fd:3 and threads can receive the message, but then threads cannot send anything back though fd:3

Is there something I am doing wrong? (line threader.js:45-59 is where the problem shows it's self)

[Package](https://github.com/Hobgoblin101/Threader) (Only on github for now while I get the package working)

Start up code:

```
var Thread = require("threader");

var task = Thread.task(function(){
  //Do some calculation
}, function(){
  //When the calculation response has been sent
});
task('a', 2);
```

Comment: Is there any example what will show up during sending

Comment: When a thread starts if logs out correctly "Loggin working" then it adds an new net.Socket({fd:3}).on('data') and when it get's any data it should just log out "RECEIVED CONENT THOUGH fd:3 in thread", after 10ms of a thread starting it should send "I piped a thing" though the net.socket, and then in the main thread it should say "Receive fd: 3 in main threader" but that never happens

Comment: Something interesting is that this code will only log out "SENT FROM THREAD 0", not anything else, it just sits there running, can fd:3 auto close or something? > https://github.com/Hobgoblin101/Threader/blob/master/test2.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured the problem:

`thread.js` is like a socket Server and `threader.js` is like a client. 

Server has to respond with in the context of the connection.

Since you are using setTimeout which itself is a separate thread that doesn't have access to the connection context, threader is not able to listen to data.

**thread.js - old code**

```
pipe.on('data', function(chunk){
  console.log('RECEIVED CONENT THOUGH fd:3 in thread');
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});

setTimeout(function () {
  pipe.write('I piped a thing');
}, 2000);
```

**thread.js - new code**

```
pipe.on('data', function(chunk){
  console.log('RECEIVED CONENT THOUGH fd:3 in thread');
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});


pipe.write('I piped a thing');
```

**OR**
**thread.js - new code - best way**

```
pipe.on('data', function(chunk){
  console.log('RECEIVED CONENT THOUGH fd:3 in thread');
  console.log(chunk.toString());
  //Real 2 second work but not on a separate thread using setTimeout
  pipe.write('I piped a thing');
});
```

Comment: I thought that timeout what just a delayed running of some code in the same thread, not a different one.

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrote the entire package again starting for a different angle and now it works...

I think the problem was to do with the thread picking.

The fixes will be pushed to github soon.

Comment: I just posted the answer. But anyhow if rewritten one is great, you should go ahead with that